# Using Route value in the controller

Tags: laravel, routes

How can I use a value in the controller that was submitted in the route?

My route looks like this:

```php
Route::get('view/{id}',  'ViewController@index');
```

I want to use the value in `{id}` in the `index` function of my `ViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass it in as an argument:

```php
class ViewController
{
    public function index($id)
    {
        // use $id
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx dude. this helpedme